# Error inicio de sesión Paypal android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, paypal

Hace algunas semanas estaba trabajando en los pagos de PayPal, todo iba perfectamente, pero luego de algunos días me comenzó a aparecer un error "error de inicio de sesión" y no se porque sucede este error.

Estoy utilizando Java en Android Studio y me comenzó a funcionar todo completamente funcional, pero al querer iniciar sesión me comenzó a aparecer eso error, estuve viendo videos de como arreglar, pero son de más de 7 años y no pude solucionarlo. Mostrare mi código del error y también mostrare el código de mi activity no estaré haciendo ninguna modificación para que vean todo como yo lo veo.

Este es el código.

dependencia:

```
implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
```

El error que no he podido solucionar es el siguiente E/paypal.sdk: request failure with http statusCode:429,exception

Codigo:

```
    private static final int PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE=7171;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config= new PayPalConfiguration().environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
            .clientId(Config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID);
    Button btnPagar;
    EditText txtMonto;
    String monto ="";

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
        startService(intent);

        btnPagar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPagar);
        txtMonto= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMonto);
        btnPagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                procesarPago();
            }
        });
    }

    private void procesarPago() {
        monto = txtMonto.getText().toString();
        PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(monto)), "MXN", "PAGADO", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payPalPayment);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                PaymentConfirmation confirmation = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirmation != null){
                    try {
                        String paymentDetails = confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (resultCode== Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){

            } else if (resultCode==PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {


            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
2021-03-15 12:49:40.612 15726-15842/app.ejemplo.test1 E/paypal.sdk: request failure with http statusCode:429,exception:
2021-03-15 12:49:40.613 15726-15842/app.ejemplo.test1 E/paypal.sdk: Exception parsing server response
    org.json.JSONException: No value for error
        at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.fj.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.fi.d(Unknown Source)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.ce.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.ci.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.cm.onResponse(Unknown Source)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
2021-03-15 12:49:40.613 15726-15842/app.ejemplo.test1 E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server response:{"name":"RATE_LIMIT_REACHED","debug_id":"5e95c5adb9bbe","message":"Too many requests. Blocked due to rate limiting.","links":[]}
2021-03-15 12:49:40.629 15726-15726/app.ejemplo.test1 W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
2021-03-15 12:49:40.632 15726-15750/app.ejemplo.test1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa685360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaa683200)
2021-03-15 12:49:40.686 15726-15750/app.ejemplo.test1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa685360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaa683200)
2021-03-15 12:49:40.688 15726-15726/app.ejemplo.test1 E/paypal.sdk: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

Actualmente mi problema es con ese error 249 que he leido de ello pero no se muestra como se puede ayudar, si me ayudaran seria de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes revisar información acerca del error 429 en la documentación de PayPal, es debido que se están enviando más de 50 solicitudes de una misma dirección en el lapso de 1 minuto.

https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/why-did-i-get-api-error-code-429-ts2115

> **Asunto**: PayPal devolvió el código de error HTTP 429: demasiadas
> solicitudes.
>
> **Causa**: Si se reciben más de 50 solicitudes de una dirección IP
> (accesos acumulados de todos los puntos finales) en 1 minuto, PayPal
> Sandbox bloqueará la IP durante los próximos 5 minutos.
>
> **solución**: Para evitar que su dirección IP se bloquee temporalmente,
> limite el número de solicitudes a menos de 50 por minuto.

**La solución es evitar a menos de 50 peticiones por minuto, el cual es el limite para PayPal.**